# Can I save Ruby memory by explicitly destroying instance variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, heroku

My rails app's memory usage increases steadily when no one uses the app, and faster when someone is. Left alone, it exceeds the Heroku limit of 512 mb in a few hours.

---

**Edit #1:** After a few changes detailed below, I observe that memory usage levels off below the max. I don't think there is a memory leak; it looks logarithmic. I will apply some stress (usage) to see how it holds up.

---

I have certain methods that create Hash, String, and (numeric) Array instance variables. Could I reduce memory usage by clearing these instance variables from memory after they are no longer needed?

I was thinking of setting the variable equal to nil after I'm done with it, or using [remove_instance_variable](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/remove_instance_variable), as in `remove_instance_variable(:@foobar)` every time I'm totally done with a variable.

Is this a sensible thing to try? If so, is this a good way of removing instance variables? Or must I run `GC.start`?

---

**Edit #2:** The only reason I am using instance variables is to pass them between multiple smaller methods, all within one Service Object. So perhaps it would use less memory to simply have one larger (less legible) method that only uses local variables? Or params taken by each smaller method? Basically, I am looking for the most memory-efficient way to run a large method that involves many variables.

---

---

**Edit #3:** After running the large method a few times in production, memory usage jumps up (from ~60% to ~80% of the max 512MB) and then stays flat. So I'm fairly sure that in addition to other ways of optimizing memory usage by the app, this particular method is a culprit.

---

I have tried several other approaches to reducing my memory usage, including:

- Deleting unneeded gems
- Changing "foo" + "bar" to "foo" << "bar"
- Reduced excessive ActiveRecord queries

In my heroku console:

```
irb(main):001:0> ObjectSpace.count_objects
=> {:TOTAL=>557200, :FREE=>116793, :T_OBJECT=>18594, :T_CLASS=>7161, :T_MODULE=>1016, :T_FLOAT=>9, :T_STRING=>261936, :T_REGEXP=>2270, :T_ARRAY=>68972, :T_HASH=>11010, :T_STRUCT=>841, :T_BIGNUM=>10, :T_FILE=>6, :T_DATA=>39779, :T_MATCH=>91, :T_COMPLEX=>1, :T_RATIONAL=>901, :T_SYMBOL=>781, :T_NODE=>24726, :T_ICLASS=>2303}
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]` (the output of `ruby -v`). Could updating ruby help? I'm also on Rails 4.2.5.1.

Comment: I asked about the version because Ruby garbage collection has had major changes in approach in 1.9.3, 2.1 and 2.2. Older versions allowed you to force garbage collection, but it seems you can't do that anymore. Also, setting an object to nil won't help you -- you need to set all references to that object to nil. GC marks and sweeps objects to which no other objects refer.

Comment: @MarsAtomic After I'm done with an object, would setting all references to that object to nil reduce memory usage? Is there a systematic way of doing just that? I'm quite sure of when I'm done with a given instance variable, so I wish I could get rid of them as soon as possible, if it would reduce memory usage.

Comment: you can manually trigger GC at certain intervals with `GC.start`

Comment: @bjhaid, are you suggesting I run GC.start at the conclusion of variable-heavy controller methods? Or rather at regular time intervals, like once every three hours?

Comment: Ah, interesting. [GC.start](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/GC.html#method-c-start) does indeed exist. GC.force was what was removed. Either way, this isn't necessarily a good solution because running GC impacts application throughput. You can make sure you expire sessions as soon as a user logs out and don't store big wads of information in those sessions, but it's hard to say what specifically you can do without seeing your code. Not running new_relic are you?

Comment: @MarsAtomic that's what I had heard, which is why I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve GC, but rather targeted destruction of variables that I know to exist and are unneeded. BTW, the reason I hadn't addressed this in my app sooner is because I never imagined that instance variables persisted and could collect like this. I'm also not convinced that GC.start is even getting everything, given how many strings are still around.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I'm not running new_relic. I'm guessing it's not a session issue because I basically have no users right now, though I'm not positive. The most variable-heavy methods create many numerous float and int vars that get updated several times throughout the methods; numerous arrays, some long, that also get updated, added and subtracted, etc.; SQL and ActiveRecord calls that I think are sensibly coded so as not to strike the database excessively; and numerous AR object creations and destructions.

Comment: I am not suggesting to run it in every controller methods, but at some interval, you store some global state that keeps track of time, and if it's pass some interval you run `GC.start`

Comment: @MarsAtomic the memory increase begins after heroku restart even when no one at all is using the app--no logins, etc. I'd be happy to post code examples if there's anything in particular that would be helpful. I was hoping that the fact that it increases without usage might provide a clue.

Comment: @bjhaid thank you, I will try that. I am also hoping for a more targeted solution since in general, I know when I am done with an instance variable and there is no longer a need to store it.

Comment: @LeoBrown the memory used by the ivar is not freed till the GC runs, so even you do whatever with it, that does not return that memory to the underlying OS

Comment: @bjhaid I see. I didn't realize it was that dependent on GC. Is it the same with local variables? Also, do you think I could save memory by splitting one long integer array into several shorter arrays?

Comment: Another option would be for me to pass the variables between the methods as parameters instead of instance variables. I am using instance variables so that they can be available between methods (all within one Service Object), not so that they can be available in a view. So perhaps parameters would be more appropriate. Another option would just be to make one giant method, which would be harder to read, but might save memory, and wouldn't actually involve the duplication of any code.